# Matching of Symbols from Bloomberg and refinitiv , for OTC derivatives trade clearing

Tags: data, bloomberg, reuters, symbology

I have been researching on this Scenario , since few days : -
Actually I have scenario , where we are dealing with OTC derivatives and BUY/SELL order can be punched in on different systems like Buy using data from  Bloomberg and Sell using Data from Refinitiv .
Both Bloomberg and Refinitiv can refer to same instrument with different SYMBOL/Code , for eg APPLE can be referred with BBG_ID -->  'X' on Bloomberg and with RIC_ID --> 'Y' on Refinitv .

Finally when post trade activities take place on our system , system should be able to identify that X & Y refer to same instrument which is Apple .

My Approach : -

1. Firstly check if the incoming Symbols/code from bloomberg and Refintiv are accompanied with ISIN and if they are accompanied with ISIN then match the ISIN to confirm if it is same security.
2. Secondly we will also need to have a look_up table in place .
3. In case ISINs are not available in STEP 1 , then we move to look up table
4. Strutcture of look_up table : -

   1. look_up identifier
   2. bloomberg_id
   3. refinitiv_id
   4. security_name
   5. cusip
   6. ticker
   7. isin
   8. sedol

- In order to have the look_up table we will need to purchase the data  from Bloomberg and other data vendors .

My question : -

Any suggestions/opinions/improvements to my approach ?

Secondly I am still doubting the fact , that even if we purchase data from vendors in order to populate the look_up table , it is still difficult to read data that data and create a single record in the look_up table for a security . Only thing that comes to my mind is Security name --> we can search by security_name in the data provided by bloomberg/Refinitiv and correspondingly make a single unique entry as per our look_up table structure .

Request : -

Please don't provide answers involving 3rd party symbology services like Magtia .
Please help me refine the mentioned approach or provide a similar approach not involving any 3rd party services

Comment: Do you care about trading venue? For example, ISINs can trade in multiple markets, whereas SEDOLs determine the venue. A specific example would be Apple. Apple trades in multiple markets with the same ISIN but different SEDOLs. This can be quite important if you're trading internationally.